# onchange of carousel image i want to execute something how do i do it? here is the code to slide

Tags: jquery

Hi,I want to call some code on change of carousel image,  how do i do it? 
here is the code to slide. please help

**JS CODE:**

```
 $("#carousel-items").carousel({
    "dot-controls": true,
    "autoplay": true,
    "autoplay-interval": 7000,
    "scroll-speed": 800,
    "skip-speed": 0,
    "left-slide-selector": "#control-left",
    "right-slide-selector": "#control-right"
 });
```

what I am trying to do is when the image in the carousel change I want to generate an event handler for that

Thanks:)

Comment: Which slider are you using? Check the doco.

Comment: provide the details about the carousel plugin which your using

Answer (score 3):

Hi I know this is an old question here is an answer for bootstrap 3

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    console.log('slide event!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the [Twitter Bootstrap Carousel](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) (since you didn't specify):

```
// This event fires immediately when the slide instance method is invoked.
$("#carousel-items").on("slide", function(){
    // do something
});

// -- OR --

// This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.
$("#carousel-items").on("slid", function(){
    // do something
});
```